# Is there any CKAN extension for Google Tag Manager?

Tags: pylons, google-tag-manager, ckan

I want to add my Google Tag Manager script to my CKAN-2.4 instance. I can manually add it by changing the template, but I want to keep it separate from CKAN code, so I was thinking separate extension is better. I searched for the extension, but I did not find anything. Can anybody tell me better approach of adding Google Tag Manager script (extension, changing template or anything else)?

Comment: Here is the CKAN extension for Google Tag Manager:
[ckanext-google_tag_manager](https://github.com/Accela-Inc/ckanext-google_tag_manager)

Answer (score 2):

[Extension](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/theming/templates.html) is the way to go, and it's easy to start.

Would be awesome if you add schema.org [tags](http://schema.org/Dataset) for dataset and [datacatalog](http://schema.org/DataCatalog) and [DataDownload](http://schema.org/DataDownload).

And once you open-source it ;), will be sure to catalog it on extensions.ckan.org.

Making judicious use of {% ckan_extends %} and {% block %} should allow you to create a Google Tag Manager extension that's readily usable in other CKAN instances.